# Random application crashes in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, cache, segmentation-fault

Sometimes after booting my computer, some applications fail to start: they crash. They're usually the largest ones, such as firefox, thunderbird or virtualbox. Rebooting or cleaning the cache usually solves the problem. For example:

```
me@localhost:~$ thunderbird &
Segmentation fault

me@localhost:~$ echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

me@localhost:~$ thunderbird &
[1] 6709
```

I've also noticed that those applications binaries or related libraries have different md5sums before and after dropping the caches. I even compared the binaries' hexdumps and found one byte difference between them.

This happens with different Linux distributions and versions. I've run memtest plenty of times, replaced my hard disk with another one (same model, though) and nothing changed. This hardware is some years old and pretty common, but this has been happening all the time since I got it, so I don't think it is unsupported.

What could I do to find the cause of this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting `OOM` messages in syslog? This sounds like OOM killer. Not sure why it would change the md5sum on your application's executables, though.

Comment: No, the word `OOM` is not present in syslog or dmesg. Total RAM is about 2gb here, are those OOM killings likely to happen just after a fresh boot?

Comment: What distro are you using? I've used Fedora for almost 3 years now and I haven't had any similar issue.

Comment: Of course those issues also don't happen on my other machines. But on this one, I've tried Fedora, Debian, now Ubuntu, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like memory errors to me. I suggest you run a memory tester like http://www.memtest.org/ for a day or two to see if that turns up any errors.

Comment: Yes, that's what I think. I've ran memtest for hours, and never found anything. Isn't it strange? Because those problems happen very frequently (one out of three boots) and it's usually just after booting. I'll try to keep memtest running for more time.

Answer (score 0):

This does look like OOM killing:

What you can do:

1. Keep checking the memory usage periodically until the programs starts crashing. You will most probably see memory usage about to hit its limits.
2. Increase the swap space. Increasing the swap may make some application response-time slower, but will prevent applications from getting killed or from getting your machine frozen.
3. If increasing the swap space fixes this, then increase the physical RAM as a permanent fix that does not have any bad side-effects.

Comment: oops, just noticed that the question was asked a few months back.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've done some tests but nothing changed after tuning memory and swap parameters. I've now replaced power supply and power strip and I've been running without issues for a couple of weeks, maybe there was some fault there